# External drive readonly when eSATA, working fine when USB

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, esata

I have a Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex external drive and I've always used with the eSATA cable. However, today I connected the drive to save some files but it didn't let me, always showing a "write protected" error.

I tried everything I found on the internet, mainly to clean attributes and take ownership (it complains to be write protected). Then, I connected the drive with a USB 3.0 cable and it worked!

Does anyone know why is that happening and how to solve it? I really need to use the eSATA cable because the USB one is not mine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the cable is defective.
I tried to connect another GoFlex with the same cable and I got the same issue.
As USB 3.0 is working fine and eSATA cable for GoFlex is discontinued, I'm staying with the USB.